High Sierra WIndowServer doesn't launch after 2020 security patch (WindowServer improperly signed)
I have (belatedly, I admit) upgraded an older Mac mini server (running Mac OS X High Sierra) with the last security update (2020-something). It now seems to hang at boot:
But, this seems not to be the case, as from the outside, it can be reached, so the OS seems to be running:
% nc -v -z 192.168.2.67 1-1000 2>&1 | grep succeeded
Connection to 192.168.2.67 port 22 [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
etc.

After some investigation it turns out WindowServer won't start because it isn't signed properly (system.log):
(com.apple.WindowServer[585]): Binary is improperly signed

It will start in safe mode, but what I need doesn't work then.
I suspect the security update requires code signed binaries, but the certificate chain is seriously out of date. Probably I need to (command line) make sure it trusts the signature nonetheless.
So, is there a way to get around this? I only need the system for one task and shortly, I do not mind the signing doesn't work. But I can't use safe mode, it seems.

I've run across some situations where setting the clock back to the approximate date that the patch was released fools the Mac into accepting an expired certificate. So if you can set the Mac's clock via command line you may be able to boot the system successfully

I did try to reset the clock to the moment it last worked (a year ago), that did not help. So, I suspect the security patch did something about the certificate store (what is accepted and what not). I will try with another date of course, but as soon as I connect it to the LAN (ethernet) it resets the date to today it seems (procedure: boot from internet, start Terminal, remove ethernet cable, set date, reboot)
